# Crystal Report automated viewer program with sorting option

Tags: sorting, parameters, crystal-reports, viewer

Does anyone know if there is a free program out there that will be able to not only view crystal reports, but also have the ability to filter data? like able to set parameters so the user can browse through the specific data they wanted, e.g sort by date.

Or is there any other reporting programs out there that provides reporting services from database and has the ability to allow end users browse it with a sorting option? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, go to http://www.freecrystalreportsviewer.com. Jeff-Net offers a free Crystal Reports viewer that allows for setting parameters and refreshing the report data.